# Using strtok with malloced pointer to string properly

Tags: c, string, pointers

I see lots of examples of strtok with arrays, but not pointers to an array. I took one at random and tried to guess how it should work. It doesn't. Why does this cause a bus error?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
   char *str = malloc(16);
   memset(str, '\0', 16);
   str = "This - is - foo";

   const char s[2] = "-";
   char *token;
   
   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);
   
   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
    
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
   
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Because this: `str = "This - is - foo";` is overwriting your pointer with a string literal. Use `strcpy` instead.

Comment: I see the difference, I had forgotten about that.

Comment: Short answer: dont use `strtok()`

Answer (score 0):

```
   char *str = malloc(16); // you allocate memory
   memset(str, '\0', 16);  // you set it to zero
   str = "This - is - foo";// you loose the reference to it assigning the pointer with the string literal reference
   // now str references string literal
   // as a bonus you got the memory leak as well
```

What can you do?:

```
   char *str = malloc(16);
   strcpy(str, "This - is - foo");
```

or simple

```
char str[] = "This - is - foo";
```

or

```
char *str = strdup("This - is - foo");
```

Comment: That makes sense.